# How to from IIS 32-Bit to 64-Bit Migration?

Tags: iis-6, migration, 32bit-64bit

How can I transfer to IIS located on Windows Server 2003 64-Bit OS  to IIS located on  Windows Server 2003 32-Bit OS ?

IIS good now working.But , When I query , that's gives me errors " Error:object reference not set to an instance of an object " etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds more like an application problem, possibly with the data.  It could also be that the application has pieces that were compiled for 64-bit which are not usable in the 32-bit environment.